# Distance between point and intersection line of plane

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine the distance from the point $(1, 3, 2)$ to the intersection line of the planes $x + y + 2z = 1$ and $x - z = 2$.

That's what i did to solve the question:

First i determined the intersection of planes $x + y + 2 z = 1$ and $x - z = 2$.

Then i got that: 
$x = -t$ and 
$y = -1-3t$ and
 $z = 2t$.

Now we can calculate the distance from point $A = (1,3,2)$ and line $(x,y,z) = (0,-1,0)+ t (-1,-3,2)$.

Then i used the formula $d=\frac{v\;\mathrm X\;pA}{|v|}$

I know that $pA = (1,4,2)$ but how about $|v \;\mathrm X\; pA|$? It's $(-14,4,-1)$ right?

So the distance will be $\sqrt \frac{213}{14}$ right?

Comment: Sorry you are right. But the cross product should be (14, 4, 1).

Answer (score 1):

Your method is correct, though it is noted in the comment you may have a slight algebra error. Here is another method, which requires some calculus but does not make use of a predetermined formula.

You have correctly identified that you wish to compute the distance from the point $p=(1,3,2)$ to the line 
$$
L(t)=(-t,-1-3\,t,2\,t)
$$
The distance from $p$ to the point $L(t)$ is given by the function
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{dist}{dist}\dist(t)=\sqrt{(1+t)^2+(4+3\,t)^2+(2-2\,t)^2}
$$
so we need only minimize $\dist(t)$. But, since $\dist(t)$ and $D(t)=\dist(t)^2$ share critical points, we can instead minimize $D(t)$ which is easier.

To do so, note that
\begin{align*}
D^\prime(t)
&= 2\,(1+t)+2\,(4+3\,t)(3)+2\,(2-2\,t)(-2) \\
&= 28\,t+18 \\
D^{\prime\prime}(t) &= 28
\end{align*}
This implies that the (global) maximum of $D(t)$ and hence $\dist(t)$ occurs at $t=-9/14$. Our answer is then
$$
\dist\left(-\frac{9}{14}\right)=\sqrt{\frac{213}{14}}
$$

Comment: Iam studying linear algebra not calculus

Comment: @hussi Calculus and linear algebra, become very interlinked, especially for multiple variables.